# fabricjs diagonal lines hovercursor and selectable

Tags: fabricjs

I have lines in fabricjs which may be at an angle. I want the user to be able to select them, but the selection outline is a rectangle with corners at the ends of the line. The user should only be able to select the line when the cursor is over the line, or at least within a few pixels of it. So I use the mousemove event to set the cursor when it's over the line and will do other things when he clicks on it.

But fabricjs only lets me set the cursor when selectable is true and then the user gets this blue rectangle around the line, which is not helpful. How can I get rid of this rectangle, or have the cursor change when selectable is false?

Answer (score 1):

First, add `perPixelTargetFind` and `targetFindTolerance` to `fabric.Canvas` instance.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
    targetFindTolerance: 5
});
```

Then, add `padding` to `fabric.Line` instance.

```
var line = new fabric.Line([50, 50, 250, 250], {
    padding: 5
});

canvas.add(line);
```

The `targetFindTolerance` numeric value is only respected by diagonal lines as far as I can tell. The `padding` numeric value is only respected by horizontal lines as far as I can tell. Both `targetFindTolerance` and `padding` must be set for either type of line to respect the rule. It's unclear whether this is buggy or intentional behavior.

Answer (score -1):

This should get you fairly close, if I understood you correctly:

[image: fabricjs no handles]

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  perPixelTargetFind: true,
  selection: false,
  hoverCursor: 'default'
});
line = new fabric.Line([50, 50, 250, 250], {
  strokeWidth: 5,
  stroke: 'black',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false,
  targetFindTolerance: 8
});
canvas.add(line);
```

And finally the all important JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/tvcufesq/.

Let me know if you have any more questions.  Always happy to help!

Comment: Thanks, only  just seen  your answer. For line I'm adding hoverCursor: 'crossHair'. And then the crosshairs show when the cursor is exactly over the line. But changing the value of targetFindTolerance doesn't seem to do anything - the cursor still has to be exactly over the line. Any thoughts?

Comment: targetFindTolerance should be a property of canvas, not line. Anyway if the line is vertical or horizontal I need to add padding because the bounding rectangle is otherwise only one pixel wide and targetFindTolerance doesn't help. But the problem then is that I use two of the corner rectangles and these are then situated at a distance from the end of the line. Can I reset these while keeping the padding?

Comment: I can try this "line.oCoords.tl.setX(100);" but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

try add padding and targetFindTolerance to line.[image: padding]

Comment: Thanks. I can't find any documentation for add padding. How does this work?